# Solidity contracts : Source control

Tags: version-control, ethereum, smartcontracts

Suppose, I wrote a contract in Solidity that is now currently being run by a number of nodes. For some reason, I made a change - code or configuration or both. How do I know that, all the nodes running this contract are running the latest version of the code?

Conversely, if the contract was placed in an open repository (e.g. GitHub), how do I know, the code wasn't tampered with?

What if, a majority of nodes **did** decide to tamper the code and run that version?

Answer (score 2):

#### Short answer

There is no "latest" version. Basically, you cannot even make a "change" to the deployed code. Please continue to read if you really need your DApp to be updatable.

#### Explanation

When you compile your Solidity source code into EVM byte code, deploy it to the blockchain (by spending some Ether), and wait for the transaction to be mined, the DApp program is fixed. During runtime, the only way that could possibly make a change in the state of the DApp is invoking a public function of the contract.

#### Solution

You may make use of the above fact to make your DApp updatable:

1. Define an interface (`Cat`) having some abstract functions (`meow`) that you want them to be updatable
2. Define a contract (`Shorthair`) that implements the interface (`contract Shorthair is Cat`)
3. Deploy the contract (`Shorthair`)
4. Define another contract (`FunMaker`)

   1. Define an `address` variable (`address catAddress`)

      - This is to store the address of your "latest" implementation
   2. In the constructor, accept an `address` parameter

      - Assign the value to `catAddress`
   3. When you want to call the updatable function (`meow`), do this:

      ```
      Cat cat = Cat(catAddress)
      cat.meow()
      ```
   4. Create another function that accepts an `address` parameter (`setCatAddress`) so that you can update the value of the `address` variable (`catAddress`)

Now, your smart contract (`FunMaker`) is updatable. When you want to make an update, just write another contract that implements `Cat` (`Shorthair2`, `Persian`, whatever) and deploy it. After the deployment, record the address and call `setCatAddress` on `FunMaker` with it to overwrite the value of `catAddress`.

#### Caveats

The spirit of smart contracts is "define what to do, do what is defined". Trust is based on the fact that nothing could be changed after deployment. However, if you implement your DApp like this, you are basically reversing the principles.

Besides, the contract being called (`Shorthair`) cannot deal with balances and variables in the caller (`FunMaker`) directly. Despite that it is still do-able with careful design and work-arounds, it is better to evaluate if it is worth doing so at the first place.

Answer (score 1):

It's organized on completely different lines.

The contract bytecode (generally from a compiler), not the source, is part of the blockchain. it's indifferent to traditional distribution channels.

The existence of the contract is part of the shared history of the chain, because the bytecode was (part of) a specific transaction that deployed the contract. Said deployment transaction is also part of the immutable history of the chain.

Nodes don't have very much latitude. They don't get to decide what version they want to run. Either they run the actual code or they cease being part of the consensus.

So, basically, you know all the nodes are running the contract you deployed, with few (if any) exceptions. It's the only correct interpretation of the chain.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Got it. For argument sake, what if the byte code execution engine were to be malicious?  Or, a majority of such engines in the network chose to be malicious.

Comment: You could have a 51% attack in which a majority of nodes decided not to alter transaction processing for a certain contract. ;-)

Comment: "Decide not to"? Or, did you mean "decided to"?

Comment: "Is Ethereum safe? I don’t think so. I absolutely cannot guarantee that the network won’t be 51% attacked (though I would like to believe that a hard fork would minimize damage from such an attack). " https://medium.com/@Vlad_Zamfir/about-my-tweet-from-yesterday-dcc61915b572#.t146ivuc4 That settles? ;)

Comment: "decided to". You asked about Source Control and I tried to help. If you found the answer useful, the next step is to Accept it or vote it up. Lengthy chats are discouraged on this site. "Is Ethereum Safe" is just too big of a topic to tackle here.

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I know the source code of the contract at a specific address?

Basically, there is no simple way.

The simplest way I can imagine is by byte code comparison:

1. Get the byte code at a specific address by [this call](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetcode)
2. Get the source code from the owner

   - In most of the cases, they are willing to provide you the source code
   - This is because the spirit of smart contracts is "define what to do, do what is defined"
   - The trust comes from the fact that the user knows exactly how it is implemented --- no more and no less
3. Compile it with a Solidity compiler

   - You may find the [official online compiler](https://remix.ethereum.org/) handy
4. Do a string comparison on the results